# Javascript $event.stopPropagation() does not work with mat-checkbox inside mat-menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular, material-design, angular15

I am struggeling to keep a material-menu open when selecting from a checkbox within it. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I've attemted solutions including changing to mat-selection-list, put each element of the menu inside a div that has (clicked)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();", and sending the clicked-event from the checkbox to a helper-method that does the same.

**example.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: 'example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['example.compontent.scss'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  subscriptions: Subscriptions[] = [];
  userSettings: ColumnInfo[] = []; // { columnName: string, isSelected: boolean }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setUserConfiguration(); // prefills userSettings
  }

  async setUserConfiguration(): Promise<void> {
  /* There's code here to pre-fill userSettings, as an example try: */
    this.userSettings = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'].foreach(col => {
      return {  columnName: col, isSelected: false }
    });

  }

  filterColumn(column: string): boolean {
    return this.userSettings.findIndex(col => col.columnName === col) !== -1;
  }

  toggleColumn(column: ColumnInfo, $event: Event): void {
    $event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault();
    column.isSelected = !column.isSelected;
  }

  someOtherFunction($event: Event): void {
    console.log($event);
  }

  public resetUserConfiguration(): void {
    this.getDefaultColumnConfiguration().then( // you can use setUserConfiguration for test
      res => this.userSettings = res as ColumnInfo[]
    );
  }
}
```

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="context" *ngIf="filterColumn('context')">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 1);">
    <div class="ps-context-menu">
      <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="tablemenu"
       test-id="open-tablemenu-btn">
        <mat-icon fontIcon="more_vert" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #tablemenu="matMenu" class="ps-ctx-no-padding filter-menu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)=someOtherFunction($event) test-id="do-something-else">
          This button does something else
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item test-id="column-properties-btn 
         [matMenuTriggerFor]="columnproperties">
          Column-properties
        </button>
        <mat-menu #columnproperties class="ps-ctx-no-padding filter-menu"
         test-id="column-properties-menu">
          <button mat-menu-item test-id="column-filter-btn [matMenuTriggerFor]="filtermenu">
            Column filter
          </button>
          <mat-menu #filtermenu class="ps-ctx-no-padding filter-menu"
           test-id="column-filter-menu">
           <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault();"
            *ngFor="let column of userSettings">
             <mat-checkbox [hidden]="column.columnName==='context'"
              [checked]="column.isSelected" (click)="toggleColumn(column, $event)">
               {{column.columnName}}
             </mat-checkbox>
           </div>
          </mat-menu>
          <button mat-menu-item test-id="column-reset-btn"
           (click)="resetUserConfiguration()">
            Reset column-selection
          </button>
        </mat-menu>
      </mat-menu>
    </div>
  </mat-header-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Looks like $event is missing in mat-checkbox (click)="toggleColumn(column)". Should be (click)="toggleColumn(column, $event)". Please check if this solves your problem. I think also that $event.stopPropagation(); should be enough.

Comment: That was an oopsie on my part. I couldn't simply copy-paste as most of the html is in another language so it wouldn't be understandable, and contains a lot of irrelevant things to this issue. Unfortunately even though the $event is passed along to the toggle-function, it does not help. I've tried both with only stopPropagation, and with preventDefault

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: @Rajat That's odd, I tried replicating with on stackblitz, but to my surprise everything is working as expected there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkufze?file=app%2Fnested-menu-example.html,app%2Fnested-menu-example.ts -- I will have to revise module-versions.

Comment: @RoyM, yeah that's weird. Perhaps try making your local and Stackblitz code same until both work fine or both break to see what may be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually realized the issue. Each time toggleColumn was called, the DOM which the menu resided upon had to be re-rendered. Therefore the menu "closed".

Setting the menu outside of this DOM solved the issue, there was never a problem using stopPropagation as I first intended.